# counter keeps resetting in a paginated post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a post to display a list of books.
I have added a counter to show the rank of the book.

It's a paginated post with 10 posts/page. The counter keeps getting back to original number when I go to the next page.

e.g :

```
Page 1  - 100, 99, ... 91
Page 2  - 100, 99, ... 91
...
Page 10 - 100, 99, ... 91
```

I want the counter to run properly showing **100 - 1**.

Here's the code I am using:

```
<?php
$postidsstring = get_field('post_ids_to_be_included');
$postidsarray = explode(", ",$postidsstring);
$countposts = count($postidsarray);
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'books',
    'post__in'       => $postidsarray,
    'orderby'        => 'post__in',
    'numberposts'    => -1,
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 10
);
$myposts = new WP_Query( $args );
$total_pages = $myposts->max_num_pages;
if ( $myposts->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $myposts->have_posts() ) : $myposts->the_post(); ?>
        <?php echo $countposts; ?>. <?php the_title(); $countposts--; ?>
        //Other details
        <br>
    <?php endwhile;
    if ($total_pages > 1) :
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base'     => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format'   => '/page/%#%',
            'current'  => $current_page,
            'total'    => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'=> __('« prev'),
            'next_text'=> __('next »'),
        ));
    endif;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

How do I correct this problem?

Edit: I am using this code to prevent the redirect to Page 1 in function.php:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    if ( is_singular( 'list' ) ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $page = ( int ) $wp_query->get( 'page' );
        if ( $page > 1 ) {
            // convert 'page' to 'paged'
            $query->set( 'page', 1 );
            $query->set( 'paged', $page );
        }
        // prevent redirect
        remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
    }
}, 0 );
```

Comment: How do these fields get populated??  Have you echo'd them out to verify they have the values you're expecting?

    $postidsstring = get_field('post_ids_to_be_included');

    $postidsarray = explode(", ",$postidsstring);

Comment: How do these fields get populated?? - Input using ACF form while creating the post. All the other fields are functioning as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution though not sure if its the right way of doing this but it works for me. I added another counter which would use the value in the variable countposts, current_page and posts_per_page to show the correct counter. Here is it:

```
<?php
$postidsstring = get_field('post_ids_to_be_included');
$postidsarray = explode(", ",$postidsstring);
$countposts = count($postidsarray);
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'books',
    'post__in'       => $postidsarray,
    'orderby'        => 'post__in',
    'numberposts'    => -1,
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 10
);
$myposts = new WP_Query( $args );
$total_pages = $myposts->max_num_pages;
if ( $myposts->have_posts() ) :
    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
    while ( $myposts->have_posts() ) : $myposts->the_post(); 
        $counter = $countposts-(($current_page-1)*$posts_per_page); ?>
        <?php echo $counter; ?>. <?php the_title(); $countposts--; ?>
        //Other details
        <br>
    <?php endwhile;
    if ($total_pages > 1) :
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base'     => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format'   => '/page/%#%',
            'current'  => $current_page,
            'total'    => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'=> __('« prev'),
            'next_text'=> __('next »'),
        ));
    endif;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

I got this solution from an old [blog post](https://multiplestates.wordpress.com/2016/10/03/add-a-post-counter-to-each-post-that-works-with-pagination/).